# dictionary and list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on my project in language computing.
My list is

```
list=["ഒരിടത്ത്‌","PR_PRP_S_NU","ചിക്കു","N_NST","എന്ന്","CC_CCD","പേരുള്ള","N_NN","ഒരു",
"QT_QTF","പട്ടികൂട്ടി","N_NN","ഉണ്ട്","V_VAUX","ആയിരുന്നു","V_VM_VF",".","RD_PUNC"]
```

I want to store these values into a dictionary  in the same order in list like

```
dict{"ഒരിടത്ത്‌":"PR_PRP_S_NU","ചിക്കു":"N_NST","എന്ന്":"CC_CCD","പേരുള്ള":"N_NN","ഒരു":"QT_QTF",
"പട്ടികൂട്ടി":"N_NN","ഉണ്ട്":"V_VAUX","ആയിരുന്നു":"V_VM_VF",".":"RD_PUNC"}
```

I worked on somany codes but the dictionary is not in the correct order as list. My code is:

```
length=len(list)
for i in range(length):
    if key=="":
        key=list[i]
        print key
    elif value=="":
        value=list[i]
        print value
    if key!="" and value!="":
        #d[key]=value
        d.update({key:value})
        key=""
        value=""
        print "item", d
print d
```

Please help we with your valuable information.

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unordered. You could try an `OderedDict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict`s are unordered, but an `OrderedDict` adds ordering functionality, from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(zip(list[::2], list[1::2]))
```

Outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('ഒരിടത്ത്‌': 'PR_PRP_S_NU'),  ('ചിക്കു': 'N_NST'),  ('എന്ന്': 'CC_CCD'),  ('പേരുള്ള': 'N_NN'),  ('ഒരു': 'QT_QTF'),  ('പട്ടികൂട്ടി': 'N_NN'),  ('ഉണ്ട്': 'V_VAUX'),  ('ആയിരുന്നു': 'V_VM_VF'),  ('.': 'RD_PUNC')])
```

The display is a little unusual (no curly braces?), but it has all the same functionality of a `dict`, with [a bit more](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Yeah I was going to come back to fix that, but then got distracted trying to figure out how to print the dang thing!

Comment: Install font to your terminal (or whatever), or use [IDLE](http://i.imgur.com/4VoqpAP.png) ;)

Comment: happy happy. I hope you also be happy.

Comment: Not a problem at all. We're happy to have you

Comment: if we use the ordereddict, whether it is possible to access the key and value of the ordereddict???

Comment: yes, in all the same ways as a standard [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)